# River Flood Warning System v2.1 - Those Pesky NoneTypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, facebook

Below is my **River Flood Warning System** version 2 build 1. After following the help and advice given for [version 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165092/river-flood-warning-system-in-python/165096?noredirect=1#comment314611_165096) the whole program is looking and behaving much better. The original code would only allow for a single river to be processed at a time, and even then not all rivers would process due to stage/flood inaccuracies. After I was finally able to solve that issue I went for my "White Whale" - The Mississippi River. With 104 stations it is the most monitored and the one river that would throw errors no matter what, but if I couldn't get the Mississippi to work then I felt that my program wouldn't really be much of a success.

So when working with the Mississippi river data, the app kept giving me

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'action' referenced before assignment.

I moved my variables around the appropriate `for` and `if` blocks, but to no avail. After asking around, I finally I just defined my variables as `None` at the begnning of the stage/flood comparisons and that seemed to  work well, except that I had to account for the **NoneTypes** in every stage of the process. This doesn't seem accurate. So my question here is **am I processing these *NoneTypes* efficiently?**

Changes from v1:

- swapped `list` operations for `dictionaries`
- put data mining/parsing and stage comparisons into seperate function
- dropped `class River()`
- implemented a file based url storage to support calling multiple urls (in dict form)

The Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' 
River Warning System v 2.1 copyright 2017 Aaron Nelson (aaron.nelson805@gmail.com
This script retrieves weather data from waterdata.usgs.gov and sends an alert to facebook when 
stage trigger has been activated

'''

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import facebook

with open('fb_river_key', 'r') as keys:
    page_key = keys.readlines() 

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = page_key)

RIVER_URL = []
with open('rivers.txt', 'r') as rivers:
    RIVER_URL = eval(rivers.read())

def check_river(url):
    ALERT_LEVELS = ["major", "moderate", "flood", "action", "low"]
    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')

    data = []

    #process the data returned from waterdata.usgs.gov
    for river in soup.select("h1.data_name"):

        river_name = river.get_text(strip=True)
        river_data = river.find_next_sibling("div")
        data.append({
            "name": river_name,
            "stage": river_data.select_one(".stage_stage_flow").get_text(strip=True).replace("Latest Stage: ", ""),
            "flood_lvl": river_data.select_one(".flood_stage_flow").get_text(strip=True).replace("Flood Stage: ", "").replace(" Feet", ""),
            "warns": river_data.select_one(".current_warns_statmnts_ads > b").next_sibling.strip(),
            "alerts": {
            alert_name: alert_value.get_text(strip=True)
            for alert_name, alert_value in
         zip(ALERT_LEVELS, river_data.select(".flood_his_lwr .box_square table tr > td:nth-of-type(2)"))
        }
    })

    #define river data per station and set conditionals
    try:
        for n in range(len(data)):
            station = data[n]['name']

            if data[n]['stage'] == 'n/a' or data[n]['stage'] == 'Latest Flow: n/a' or data[n]['stage'] == 'Latest Stage: n/a':
                pass
            else:
                stage = float(data[n]['stage'])
                if data[n]['alerts'] == None:
                    pass
                else:
                    action = None
                    flood = None
                    moderate = None
                    major = None
                    for a in ALERT_LEVELS:
                        if a in data[n]['alerts'] and a != None:
                            action = float(data[n]['alerts']['action'])
                            flood = float(data[n]['alerts']['flood'])
                            moderate = float(data[n]['alerts']['moderate'])
                            major = float(data[n]['alerts']['major'])
                            warn = data[n]['warns']

                            if major == 0:
                                pass
                            elif moderate == 0:
                                pass
                            elif flood == 0:
                                pass   
                            elif action == 0 and flood != 0:
                                action = flood  
                        else:
                            pass                    

                    if stage != None and action != None and stage < action :
                        pass
                    elif stage != None and major != None and major != 0 and stage > major :
                        graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed', message=('The {} has reched [Major Flood Stage: ({}Ft)] @ {}Ft.\n\n***Warnings***\n{}\n\nPlease click the Link below for more information.'.format(station, major, stage, warn)))#, link = RIVER_URL)
                    elif stage != None and moderate != None and moderate != 0 and stage > moderate:
                        maj_diff = round((major - stage), 2)
                        graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed', message=('The {} has reached [Moderate Flood Stage: ({}Ft)] @{}Ft.\n\nNext stage is [Major Flood Stage] in {}ft.\n\n***Warnings***\n{}\n\nPlease click the Link below for more information.'.format(station, moderate, stage, maj_diff, warn)))#link = RIVER_URL)
                    elif stage != None and flood != None and flood != 0 and stage > flood:
                        mod_diff = round((moderate - stage), 2)
                        graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed', message=('The {} has reached [Flood Stage: ({}Ft)] @ {}Ft.\n\nNext stage is [Moderate Flood Stage] in {}Ft.\n\n***Warnings***\n{}\n\nPlease click the Link below for more information.'.format(station, flood, stage, mod_diff, warn)))#, link = RIVER_URL)
                    elif stage != None and action != None and action != 0 and stage > action:
                        flood_diff = round((flood - stage), 2)
                        graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed', message=('The {} has reached [Action Flood Stage: ({}Ft)] @ {}Ft.\n\nNext stage is [Flood Stage] in {}Ft.\n\n***Warnings***\n{}\n\nPlease click the Link below for more information.'.format(station, action, stage, flood_diff, warn)))#, link = RIVER_URL)

    except KeyError:
        raise

if __name__ == '__main__':

     for url in RIVER_URL:       
       check_river(RIVER_URL[url])
```

**And the results**: *note Normally the results post to what ever account your Facebook Key is set for. For testing purposes I just print to console so I'm not spamming my FB page.*

```
skywalker@endor:~/scripts/python/riverwarn$ ./riverwarn.py
Sabine River At Deweyville (DWYT2) stage (24.09) is above [FLood Stage: 24.0]
Mississippi River At Lynxville (LYNW3) stage (619.36) is above [Action Stage: 619.0]
Mississippi River At Burlington (BRLI4) stage (14.22) is above [Action Stage: 14.0]
Mississippi River At Canton Lock and Dam 20 (CANM7) stage (12.44) is above [Action Stage: 12.0]
Mississippi River At Hannibal (HNNM7) stage (15.52) is above [Action Stage: 14.0]
Mississippi River At Saverton Lock and Dam 22 (SVRM7) stage (14.38) is above [Action Stage: 14.0]
Mississippi River At Louisiana (LUSM7) stage (14.9) is above [Action Stage: 13.0]
Mississippi River At Clarksville Lock and Dam 24 (CLKM7) stage (25.54) is above [FLood Stage: 25.0]
Mississippi River At Winfield Lock and Dam 25 (CAGM7) stage (26.1) is above [FLood Stage: 26.0]
Mississippi River At Grafton (GRFI2) stage (19.03) is above [FLood Stage: 18.0]
Mississippi River At Chester (CHSI2) stage (27.01) is above [FLood Stage: 27.0]
Mississippi River At Cape Girardeau (CPGM7) stage (32.45) is above [FLood Stage: 32.0]
Mississippi River At Thebes (THBI2) stage (30.68) is above [Action Stage: 30.0]
Mississippi River Near Greenville (GEEM6) stage (47.75) is above [Action Stage: 36.0]
Mississippi River At Vicksburg (VCKM6) stage (43.94) is above [FLood Stage: 43.0]
Mississippi River At Natchez (NTZM6) stage (52.08) is above [Moderate FLood Stage: 51.0]
Mississippi River At Red River Landing (RRLL1) stage (55.66) is above [Moderate FLood Stage: 55.0]
Mississippi River At Baton Rouge (BTRL1) stage (38.45) is above [Moderate FLood Stage: 38.0]
Mississippi River At Donaldsonville (DONL1) stage (27.94) is above [FLood Stage: 27.0]
Mississippi River At Reserve (RRVL1) stage (22.35) is above [FLood Stage: 22.0]
```

Here is a sample *rivers.txt* file for anyone interested:

```
{'redriver':'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/river.php?wfo=SHV&wfoid=18715&riverid=203413&pt%5B%5D=all&allpoints=143204%2C147710%2C141425%2C144668%2C141750%2C141658%2C141942%2C143491%2C144810%2C143165%2C145368&data%5B%5D=xml', 'sabine':'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/river.php?wfo=HGX&wfoid=18770&riverid=203330&pt%5B%5D=all&allpoints=143588%2C143271%2C141876%2C141823%2C143740%2C143862%2C143045%2C144247%2C144246%2C141799&data%5B%5D=xml', 'riogrande':'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/river.php?wfo=crp&wfoid=18767&riverid=204592&pt%5B%5D=all&allpoints=144166%2C144467%2C143214%2C143547%2C142661%2C143437%2C151195%2C144782%2C142474%2C141927%2C143988%2C144335%2C151375%2C151376%2C151377%2C141895%2C151378%2C141579%2C141562%2C151365%2C144387%2C151379%2C144104%2C151438%2C151443%2C151444%2C144623%2C141482%2C141924%2C143303%2C148129%2C145933%2C142442%2C144066%2C141780%2C144293%2C146608%2C144871%2C144021%2C144722%2C141667%2C144458%2C143692%2C145293%2C142278%2C143836%2C141362%2C141311%2C142508%2C141834&data%5B%5D=xml', 'guadalupe':'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/river.php?wfo=CRP&wfoid=18767&riverid=203902&pt%5B%5D=all&allpoints=144345%2C143598%2C142553%2C144328%2C143865%2C143130%2C151580%2C143240%2C142456%2C142351%2C152768%2C142305%2C152767%2C144199%2C144786%2C142458%2C141593%2C152182&data%5B%5D=xml', 'mississippi':'http://water.weather.gov/ahps2/river.php?wfo=jan&wfoid=18743&riverid=203833&pt%5B%5D=all&allpoints=143846%2C142736%2C143816%2C143998%2C145144%2C142659%2C145887%2C144081%2C142375%2C143866%2C141506%2C142962%2C143885%2C153060%2C143323%2C144201%2C144542%2C142873%2C143260%2C143099%2C142560%2C144186%2C143177%2C142054%2C143945%2C144055%2C141370%2C143630%2C141931%2C142812%2C141676%2C142534%2C144568%2C143535%2C144589%2C143030%2C144031%2C143079%2C144282%2C141445%2C141722%2C141383%2C143445%2C143646%2C152882%2C143787%2C143574%2C143545%2C142773%2C141629%2C144517%2C142500%2C143196%2C142105%2C142509%2C142418%2C152996%2C152997%2C152998%2C144108%2C141463%2C152999%2C153000%2C153001%2C153002%2C152909%2C141839%2C143934%2C141618%2C146423%2C143366%2C147048%2C142172%2C151794%2C153107%2C141493%2C142940%2C144619%2C144798%2C151521%2C151430%2C144609%2C151338%2C141308%2C151468%2C144449%2C143828%2C151447%2C151342%2C142711%2C151473%2C151474%2C151475%2C151469%2C151476%2C151477%2C151448%2C151450%2C151455%2C151478%2C151451%2C151479%2C151480%2C151452&data%5B%5D=xml'}
```